# Database from Excel Sheets

Tags: database, excel, import, etl

I have a problem statement.

A client of mine has three years of data in very complicated Excel Sheets. They are currently doing data entry, reporting and every thing basically in excel and these excels are shared with each other when ever there is a need to share the data.

They want eventually to move to a web based solution.

The first step of the solution agreed is to make a routine and a database. The routine will import the data from excels into the database. The database itself will need to be designed in such a way that the same database can be used at the back for a web site.

The said routine will be used as a one time activity to import all the data for the last three years and also will be used on periodic basis so that they keep importing the data until the web front is ready or agreed upon.

The defacto method for me is to analyze the excel sheets, make a normalized database, make a service in java that will use poi, read the excel sheets, apply business logic and insert the data into the database. The problem here is that any time they change the excel or even the data format, the routine will need to be rewritten.

I am willing to go any way, maybe use an ETL tool.

Please recommend.

Comment: This question seems overly broad for SO, you might read http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/no-one-answers

Comment: YODKP (You Obviously Don't Know Perl).

Comment: I use Pentaho Data Integration (an ETL tool) extensively, so I would lean towards using that. It can easily do what you're saying and it's quite easy to change the transform when you need to. There is a bit of a learning curve with it, but in my experience it's worth it.